# MySQL select groups having active subscriptions

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, join

I have two table in my DB i.e.

```
groups

id|name|created_at|updated_at

subscriptions
id|name|group_id|status|created_at|updated_at
```

I am looking for a single MySQL query to get all the groups that have active subscriptions.
I know I can do it in `foreach` but it would be really helpful if there is a way by doing this in `mysql`.

TIA

Comment: How do we know that a given subscription is active?

Comment: Looking? Looking where? :-(

Answer (score 2):

Below Query will help you to get all active groups

```
SELECT g.* FROM groups g INNER JOIN subscriptions s ON g.id = s.group_id
WHERE s.status = 1;
```

Thanks,
Let me know if you need further help.

Answer (score 0):

You need a simple join -

```
SELECT S.id, S.name, S.group_id, S.status
FROM groups G
INNER JOIN subscriptions S ON G.id = S.group_id
WHERE S.status = 'Active'
```